# GET method auto remove trailing whitespace

Tags: html, get, whitespace

I use GET method the send a text to server such as: 'abc ', but the GET method always remove the whitespace characters at the end, so the server received 'abc' but not 'abc '

I want to ask whether this is the property of GET method?

Is there any way to use GET to send text without removing trailing whitespace.

Comment: most browsers do something similar to rtrim in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to encode the URL to convert spaces to their equivalent %20.

PHP has a [`rawurlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) function which caters for this.
[Here](http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode/) is a way of doing this in JavaScript.